# Shortcut to EQ in iOS?

Tags: ios, music

Is there a way to create a shortcut to the Settings->Music->EQ in iOS? Sometimes with my headphones I like to activate Bass Booster, but want to turn it off when listening via Bluetooth in my car...

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to create shortcuts into the Settings app like that (from a user perspective).